# android activity to activity communication

Tags: android

I have an activity A which has socket communication, and I'm opening activity B on click of a button with intent from Activity A.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    //open preferences activity
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreferencesActivity.class);
                    //using some bundle here to send data
                    .....
                    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
               }
```

Now, if at all any socket communication happens in activity A then I have to identify that (some communication happened in activity A) in activity B and need to close activity B and bring the activity A to foreground as well. Socket communication is as follows.

```
 ConnectSocket();
 while (true) {
        //wait for socket client
        socClient = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
        //once socket is connected send it back to activity
        if (socClient != null) {
            if (socketThread != null) {
                   connectedSocket = socClient;
                   socClient = null;
                   communicationThread = new ReadSocketThread();
                   communicationThread.start();
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

Here ReadsocketThread() is a thread that read the socket for messages.

How to notify activity B that something happened in activity A. I tried using handler to send message but not successful as handler in activity A never sends message to activity B. As a beginner, may be I am not using properly.

Comment: 1> use local broadcast manager.- register broadcast in one activty and send broadcast from other activity.

2> use bound service.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i used localbroadcastmanager is able to communicate... a good link with sample code is found here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager

Comment: Good , make sure you are not updating any UI after activity onstop  system callback

Answer (score 0):

A workaround approach is to use `EventBus` in Android. To use `EventBus`:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Then, create an event to receive message from Activity A

```
    public class HelloWorldEvent {
    private final String message;

    public HelloWorldEvent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Then create a sender from Activity A :

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new HelloWorldEvent("Hello EventBus!”);
```

Then, you can add as many listeners as you require, as in your case , in Activity B:

```
    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(HelloWorldEvent event){
  // your implementation
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So, what happens here is whenever `EventBus.getDefault().post(new HelloWorldEvent("Hello EventBus!”);` is invoked from Activity A, you'd get the Toast in Activity B, you can pass your preferred message there. A more detailed example on `EventBus` is available [[here]](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/11/28/android-how-to-use-the-greenrobot-eventbus/)

Answer (score 0):

I found another simple solution for my scenario as I do not need to pass any message between activities, instead on socket communication want to close activity B and bring activity A to foreground. I achieved this without using any broadcast or event bus by just opening the Activity B with

```
 startActivityForResult(intent, somerequestcode);
```

and when there is communication to activity A, at the appropriate position simply call

```
finishActivity(somerequestcode);
```

note : somerequestcode can be any integer